# Trying to select link in other element with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

So i'm working on a plugin for a specific site, i'm trying to select a certain link but only if the image next to it has a certain title.

The only problem here is that the image and the link aren't in the same element, and i'm not quite sure how to target the link.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/93U3N/2/)

```
$('div.column.first img[title="True"]').css({
    "background-color": "red"
});

$("div.column a").parent().css({"background-color": "red"});
```

This is all the code I have ( I know its not much but i'm completely stuck )

Could anyone please give a hint on how I should approach this, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('div.column.first img[title="True"]').parent().siblings().find('a').css({
    "background-color": "red"
});
```

You can also use the `.next()` method instead of the `.siblings()`. Based on your markup an alternative is using the `.has()` method:

```
$('li.even').has('img[title="True"]').find('a').css({
    "background-color": "red"
});
```

Or `:has` selector:

```
$('li.even:has(img[title="True"]) a').css("background-color", "red");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('div.column.first img[title="True"]').css({
    "background-color": "red"
});
$('div.column.first img[title="True"]')
    .parent() //Select Parent
    .next() //Next Div
    .find('a')
    .css({"background-color": "red"});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/93U3N/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
$('.column').find("img[title='True']").closest("li").find("a").css({"background-color": "red"});
```

You only need to look for the img inside the column class, find the li then the link and change the css. My suggestion would be put some more classes, in the link mostly. And you could use the [data](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) attribute instead title if you can change of course.